# Is it possible to get @ and . for iPhone when I'm using input type="password"?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, input, passwords

I'm making a login page for my iPhone app.

But when I make a text field for typing-in password using
input type="password" ~, the phone shows a typical keyboard that displays the alphabet in capital letters.

But I want to make text field for password, but shows a keyboard that displays @ and . button, similar to that of when using input type ="email" ~.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: I think `autocapitalize="none"` and `pattern` are what you are looking for

Comment: do I need to change my input type? Do you mean like input type = "password", autocapitalize="none" pattern = "[0-9]*"~ ?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, but `pattern = "[0-9]*"` for numbers